# Regex to remove 1. texts within parenthesis 2.numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I can't seem to find the right regex for what I need. My data frame contains the following countries:

```
Switzerland17,
Iran (Islamic Republic of),
China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
```

I would like 17 to be removed from Switzerland and all text within parenthesis to be removed.  So far, I only managed to do one or the other.
Ps.: "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region" should remain the same

My current incomplete code:

```py
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace("[^a-zA-Z]",'')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\s*\([^()]*\)|\d+", "", regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU7AUO/1).

If you also need to remove optional whitespace before digits, you can group the two patterns after `\s*`:

```py
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|\d+)", "", regex=True)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU7AUO/2).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\([^()]*\)|\d+)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - one or more digits